# What does the green dot with yellow star mean in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I have searched in google but unfortunately couldn't find any answers, so the question is:
What this symbol [image]means in eclipse? (eclipse version : neon.1 for EE developers)
(It is known that the green dot indicates a method but what about the yellow star?)

Update:[image] In this image you can see 8 methods that have the star symbol.

Comment: How is it related to java?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Eclipse is an Ide that supports many programming languages.Decorators changed based on the selected language.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of where it's occuring? Will provide more context to the question

Comment: Is this in the outline or somewhere else? What is the actual method declaration?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completion proposals with that icon are contributed by [Code Recommenders](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/). That plugin leverages external information to recommend more relevant proposals, as you can also see by the percentage shown beside each entry: it indicates s.t. like the probability that the given proposal is what you need in your context.

You will also find mention of Code Recommenders and how it intergrates with JDT in the preferences under `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it have a tooltip? Just hover over it and see what it says.

That might be a custom icon that was introduced by a certain Eclipse plugin that you installed. To figure out what plugin it relates to, go to Window -> Customize Perspective. There, under Tool Bar Visibility tab, you will see the tool bar structure. You can expand each section to see the list of functions and the related icons. Your icon should be there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse generally sorts methods alphabetically.

To ease users, top used methods are listed before the alphabetical sorting; think of System.out where println will be on top.

Another case is when a certain return type is expected, say for any arbitrary object:

```
String str = obj.
```

toString() will be on the top.

Methods like these are starred.